# Do I need to call the destructor of vector in this scenario

Tags: c++

Now I implement a class and I need to use vector to hold some pointers.This is a global member.
    vector g_vIPControlCollection;

When the system finalize. I want to reclaim the memory. Then I define the destroy method.

```
void Destroy()
{
    int size = g_vIPControlCollection.size();
    if (size > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            g_vIPControlCollection[i]->Release();
        }
    }
    g_vIPControlCollection.clear();
    g_vIPControlCollection.~vector<IPersistorControl*>(); //Does this line is necessary?
}
```

My question is whether I need to call destructor of the vector? Thanks in advance. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you should not, what you should do is use a [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to manage your `IPersistorControl` objects for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Point{
    int x; int y;
    Point(int x,int y): x(x), y(y){}
    ~Point(){ cout<< "destroying " << y<<endl;}
};

int main() {
    {
        vector<unique_ptr<Point>> ps;
        ps.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Point>(new Point(1,2)));
        ps.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Point>(new Point(1,3)));
        ps.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Point>(new Point(1,4)));
    } // will call dtors here
    cout << "Example 1" <<endl;
    {
        vector<unique_ptr<Point>> ps;
        ps.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Point>(new Point(1,2)));
        ps.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Point>(new Point(1,3)));
        ps.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Point>(new Point(1,4)));
        ps.clear(); // will call them here
        cout << "Example 2" <<endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if `IPersistorControl` is some object that needs a special type that requires some other method of "reclaiming" (e.g windows handles or file handles) you can specify a Deleter e.g:

```
unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)> filePtr(fopen("LALA.txt", "wb"), fclose);
                     ^                                            ^
                    Deleter type                              the actual Deleter
```

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you did that, after the call to `Destroy` it would be left in an invalid state. It will self destruct when its owner gets destroyed.

And your `Destroy` function should probably be a destructor, too.

Answer (score 1):

No you should almost never call the [destructor explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720201/calling-destructor-explicitly).

What you need to do here is just `g_vIPControlCollection.clear();` that you are already doing. After this `std::vector` hardly keeps any memory (typically 12 bytes on 32 bit machines) and would be cleaned when the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You shouldn't and needn't call destructor manually. That would
   result in destructor invocation **two** times ( 1 by you and 1 when
   object goes out of scope), affecting object state and your program
   might crash at best. See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d413531005b357f9)
2. It is good and recommended practice to clear memory allocated. But since it is a
   global object, and program is going to terminate, even if you don't
   free memory, it will reclaimed as process terminates.
3. Try using `std::unique_ptr<>` for storing pointers in `std::vector`
   so that memory will be released when the `clear` method in
   invoked on `std::vector`. This way you don't have to iterate and manually invoke the `Release` method of each member of `std::vector`

Comment: As the Release is not the destructor of the object and it is only used to decrease the reference counter. Does the smart pointer can call it automatically when the vector clears all the members?

Comment: @Goleo8 No. It won't. But if you wanted a reference counted object, wasn't `std::shared_ptr<>` the better choice ? I mean who ever ( client ) gets the objects, should received it as `std::shared_ptr<>`. For more http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824317/1180117